# Mouse click prevention in javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I have several buttons like Load File, Save File, Deploy. I add some visualize object into visualization area.  After clicking Load File button, I want to prevent mouse click event(in Visualization Area. Not for the other buttons and you can see the image). When I click the other buttons, I want to activate mouse click event again. Only load button deactivate mouse click event for visualization area and other buttons will activate mouse click event for visualization area again. How can I achieve that?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiyg3.jpg)

My Load File button function as below.

```
button()
.container(g3)
.text(text3)
.count(2)
.cb(function() {
        console.log("Load File");
        console.log("nodes", nodes);
        console.log("Reading JSON File");
        loadFlag = true;
        clearFlag = false;
        update();
})();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean you want to disable some HTML buttons in your page ?

Comment: The `cb` function returns a function or this is just your partial script?

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting a CSS attribute on the button container element (`div` for example):

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Or in JQuery:

```
$("#button_container_div_id").css("pointer-events", "none");
```

Comment: It's much cleaner to just disable the button

Comment: That's not what the OP wanted - and also - disabling changes style

Answer (score 0):

You can disable all the buttons except a `#load` button. Toggle the `disable` property on click on `#load` button.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/shubham_agr10/gm7t7ymf/)

Here is the code

```js
$('#load').click(function() {
  $('button').not(this).prop('disabled', function(_, val) {
    return !val;
  });
});
// TO check whether the other buttons are disabled or not
$('button').not("#load").click(function() {
  alert("CLICKED");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="load">
  Load
</button>
<button id="file">
  FILE
</button>
<button id="file1">
  FILE 1
</button>
<button id="file2">
  FILE 2
</button>
<button id="file3">
  FILE 3
</button>
```